# SQL - divide one column by another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
select c.category
,sum(b.is_open) as open
,count(b.name) as total
from business b inner join category c on b.id=c.business_id
group by c.category
order by sum(b.is_open) desc
limit 10
```

which gives me following dataset:

```
+------------------+------+-------+
| category         | open | total |
+------------------+------+-------+
| Restaurants      |   53 |    71 |
| Shopping         |   25 |    30 |
| Food             |   20 |    23 |
| Health & Medical |   16 |    17 |
| Home Services    |   15 |    16 |
| Beauty & Spas    |   12 |    13 |
| Nightlife        |   12 |    20 |
| Bars             |   11 |    17 |
| Active Life      |   10 |    10 |
| Local Services   |   10 |    12 |
+------------------+------+-------+
```

However, if I change line 2 and 3 to:

```
sum(b.is_open) / count(b.name) as '%'
```

instead of a specific value, I get zeroes all along. I tried to cast both columns to decimal type (although looks like they have been such in the beginning), did not work. Why can't I get the right results? I am writing my queries in SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **floating point arithmetic** instead of integer arithmetic:

```
1.0 * sum(b.is_open) / count(b.name) as '%'
```